# Remove Search box from Magento Home page

Tags: php, xml, magento

How to remove search box from home page in magento.

I searched in `CMS > Pages > home` page, no code related to search box was available.

I can remove search  box in every catalog view and product view page using this link

"http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/38420/".

How to remove from home page.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the app/design/frontend/YOUR_THEME_NAME/default/template/page/html/header.php
Line no:- 38 Please Use this code.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
```

to

```
<?php if(Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() != 'home'  && Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms') : ?>

<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>

<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is i have to follow your solution for all THEME NAMES in my site. I am using 15 THEME NAMES.

Comment: Yes you have to put this code into every header.php file in which you don't want to show the search on home page.

Comment: @Vikasrao:brother if it help then please check as right on my answer so its help to other also

Answer (score 1):

you can remove by xml

Create local.xml under `app/design/frontend/yourpakcage/yourtemplate/layout/`

Code of

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <cms_index_index >
    <reference name="root">
    <remove name="top.search" />
        </reference>
    </cms_index_index>
</layout>
```

Comment: Hi, I have many packages in my site. I used the above solution for only one package. but it did't removed search box from home page. Is i have to create local.xml in every package that i have in my site. i have about 15 packages in my  site. will search box will remove from home page, if i follow your solution for all 15 packages.

Comment: which package  are using for you site.For check this package name in your site goto to admin>system>configuration>general>design ,here you   will find you current used package

Comment: I  created many packages and i have 15 grouped products in my site overall. i am using 15 packages. because on the top of every grouped product[in a product view page] , i have to mention different texts, so i am using different packages for different products. so for removing search box in home page, is i have to follow your solution for all packages....

Comment: then we need create local.xml for packages

Comment: Sure, I will create local.xml for all packages.... i will try that.... thanks....

Comment: You can also add this to `default.xml` and it will change globally.

Answer (score 1):

use following xml

```
<?xml>
<layout>
  <default>    
     <reference name="header">
       <remove name="top.search" />
     </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: Hi, I have many packages in my site. I used the above solution for only one package. but it did't removed search box from home page. Is i have to create local.xml in every package that i have in my site. i have about 15 packages in my  site. will search box will remove from home page, if i follow your solution for all 15 packages.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the search function from the home page using a layout update.
on the page you wish to remove this from, goto the design tab.
In the 'custom design' tab and in the 'Custom layout update XML' box add in the following:

```
<remove name="top.search" />
```

This will remove the search box from this page only.
Worked for me when all i wanted to do was remove the top search from the home page only.